# linger.ms not working as expected in Spring Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I've a use case where I need to do batch processing using Kafka. Suppose if there are some 100 requests coming in 1 Minute, instead of publishing each request immediately, I wanted to batch all the 100 requests and publish it to topic once.

But with the below configuration, batch processing is not happening, as soon as a message is sent it is getting published to topic and simultaneously received in consumer

**ProducerConfig**

```
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

  @Bean
  public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, 1);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 0);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION, 1);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 60000);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 100000);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "lz4");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.PARTITIONER_CLASS_CONFIG, DefaultPartitioner.class);
    return props;
  }

  @Bean
  public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
  }

  @Bean
  public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
  }

}
```

**ConsumerConfig**

```
public class KafkaConfig {

  ConsumerFactory<String, String> kafkaConsumerFactory(Boolean autoCommit) {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, autoCommit);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 1000);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 20000);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 5);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "batch");
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
  }



  @Bean("kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
        new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(kafkaConsumerFactory(Boolean.TRUE));
    factory.setBatchListener(true);
    factory.setConcurrency(1);
    return factory;
  }
  
}
```

Here I've set linger.ms = 60000 and as per my understanding if linger.ms is set to some value, then producer will wait at least for that amount of time even if sender thread became available earlier and batch size is not reached.

But here in my case as soon as a message is sent it is getting published to topic without waiting for 60000 ms or for batch size to reach the value which is being set

**Producer**

```
  @Autowired
  private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafka;

  kafka.send("batch-test", message);
```

**Consumer**

```
  @KafkaListener(id = "testGroup", topics = {"batch-test"})
  public void test(@Payload List<String> messages, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) List<Integer> partitions,
      @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) List<Long> offsets) {
    for (int i = 0; i < messages.size(); i++) {
      System.out.println(messages.get(i) + partitions.get(i) + "-" + offsets.get(i) + "");
    }
  }
```

**Small Update here**
I checked the Spring kakfa logs and found that ProducerConfig values are not being set properly, they are falling back to default values

```
roducerConfig values: 
acks = -1
batch.size = 16384
bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
buffer.memory = 33554432
client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
client.id = producer-1
compression.type = none
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
enable.idempotence = true
interceptor.classes = []
key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
linger.ms = 0
```

Why is **linger.ms** and **batch.size** is falling back to default values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution for this, `linger.ms` was not causing any effect because the value was not being set from the code (still don't know why). Hence the `linger.ms` has its default value as 0 because of which batching was not happening.

Later I set the value for both `linger.ms` and `batch.size` in the application.properties then it worked.

```
spring.kafka.producer.batch-size=1000000
spring.kafka.producer.properties.linger.ms=10000
```

Comment: It looks like you were using Boot's auto configured producer factory instead of your own. DEBUG logging should help you figure out why (Boot's auto configuration report).

Answer (score 2):

As far as my understanding BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG (batch.size) will work perfectly along with LINGER_MS_CONFIG (linger.ms), only when multiple records intended to send to the same partition, but not across the partitions, that means, you should be having some keying mechanism or better partitioning strategy in place to achieve batching while producing events into the topic.

From Doc:

### batch.size

When multiple records are sent to the same partition, the producer will batch them
together. This parameter controls the amount of memory in bytes (not messages!)
that will be used for each batch. When the batch is full, all the messages in the batch
will be sent. However, this does not mean that the producer will wait for the batch to
become full. The producer will send half-full batches and even batches with just a sin‐
gle message in them. Therefore, setting the batch size too large will not cause delays
in sending messages; it will just use more memory for the batches. Setting the batch
size too small will add some overhead because the producer will need to send mes‐
sages more frequently.

### linger.ms

linger.ms controls the amount of time to wait for additional messages before send‐
ing the current batch. KafkaProducer sends a batch of messages either when the cur‐
rent batch is full or when the linger.ms limit is reached. By default, the producer will
send messages as soon as there is a sender thread available to send them, even if
there’s just one message in the batch. By setting linger.ms higher than 0, we instruct
the producer to wait a few milliseconds to add additional messages to the batch
before sending it to the brokers. This increases latency but also increases throughput
(because we send more messages at once, there is less overhead per message).

Comment: this I've tested with only 1 partition

Comment: And ProducerConfig values are not being set, they are falling back to default values

`ProducerConfig values: 
 acks = -1
 batch.size = 16384
 bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
 buffer.memory = 33554432
 client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
 client.id = producer-1
 compression.type = none
 connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
 delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
 enable.idempotence = true
 interceptor.classes = []
 key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
 linger.ms = 0`

**Updated this in the question also**